# How to align the cursor under a specific character?

Tags: vim, alignment

Sometimes when coding in vim I'd like to start a new line and align the cursor under a specific character. For example:

```
(,) <$> foo

    ^ -- I want to align here to continue typing like:
    <*> bar
```

Is there an easy way how to do it?

**Update:** It'd be also nice to be able to split a line and align at the same. Let's say I'm editing line

```
(,) <$> foo <*> bar
            ^ -- cursor here
```

and I'd like to split the line so that it gets aligned as

```
(,) <$> foo
    <*> bar
    ^ -- cursor here
```

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31123334/1333025).

Answer (score 2):

With

```
:set virtualedit=all
```

you can first create the new line (e.g. `o<Esc>`), position the cursor on that "specific character" (e.g. with `kf{char}`), then just move the cursor into the same column of the new line and start editing (`ji`).

Answer (score 0):

If you use 0 or $ to jump frequently,
`set virtualedit=insert,block`
instead of
`set virtualedit=all`

```
set virtualedit=insert,block
" toggle virtualedit
    let s:anywhere = 0
    func! Cursor_anywhere_01()
        if s:anywhere == 0
                set virtualedit=insert,block
                " set virtualedit=all # 会导致光标跳转不舒服                                                                                                  let s:anywhere = 1
        else
            set virtualedit=
            let s:anywhere = 0
        endif
        set virtualedit?
    endfunc
    nnoremap <Leader>aw :call Cursor_anywhere_01()<cr>
```